# Does Xamarin.Forms UWP app support .NET 6 ? I tried to migrate Xamarin.Forms UWP app from .NET Standard to .NET 6. I am getting couple of errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I modified the below code for Shared Project,

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Plan to migrate to Maui, which targets WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) instead of UWP. UWP is deprecated for new .NET projects.